# Use Autofac with WCF service with InstanceContextMode = PerSession

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, autofac

I have a WCF service with `ServiceBehavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession`.

How do I need to register the service with Autofac to get a new instance for each new session but use the same instance in the session?
I am currently using the following configuration and it leads to behavior like `PerCall`:

```
builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IUserService>()).SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IUserService>>().CreateChannel())
       .UseWcfSafeRelease();
builder.RegisterType<UserService>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: what kind of binding are you using. basicHttpBinding does not support `PerSession` Behavior. Also WCF already takes care of itself by managing sessions.

Comment: Indeed, I use `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to just change the binding to a wsHttpbinding. I'm not home but you can find plenty of resources for bindings in wcf

Comment: Please post your comments as an answer, I will accept it than. I wasn't aware of the fact, that basicHttpBinding doesn't support PerSession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out during the comments you were using basicHttpBinding. basicHttpBinding doesn't support `ServiceBehavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` Session Behaviour. For more details on bindings, check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx)

What I also like to add is that WCF automaticly keeps track of its session an if you close the proxy and reopen again you will get the same session. (If your binding of course supports it). Only when the client is closed your session will be terminate automaticly in WCF.